# EKRecurrenceRule for working days in a week

Tags: ios, xcode, ios4

I am creating simple application that has ability to add events into iPhone Calendar. So I am playing with EKEvent's recurrenceRule. There is a class EKRecurrenceRule with very long constructor:

```
(id)initRecurrenceWithFrequency:(EKRecurrenceFrequency)
                   typeinterval:(NSInteger)interval 
                  daysOfTheWeek:(NSArray *)days 
                 daysOfTheMonth:(NSArray *)monthDays 
                monthsOfTheYear:(NSArray *)months 
                 weeksOfTheYear:(NSArray *)weeksOfTheYear 
                  daysOfTheYear:(NSArray*)daysOfTheYear 
                   setPositions:(NSArray *)setPositions 
                            end:(EKRecurrenceEnd*)end
```

So for example, if I am trying to create a event that will be repeated every work day in the week (except Sunday), I will use this init:

```
initRecurrenceWithFrequency:EKRecurrenceFrequencyDaily 
                   interval:1 
              daysOfTheWeek:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                [EKRecurrenceDayOfWeek dayOfWeek:2],
                                [EKRecurrenceDayOfWeek dayOfWeek:3],
                                [EKRecurrenceDayOfWeek dayOfWeek:4],
                                [EKRecurrenceDayOfWeek dayOfWeek:5], 
                                [EKRecurrenceDayOfWeek dayOfWeek:6],
                                [EKRecurrenceDayOfWeek dayOfWeek:7], nil] 
            daysOfTheMonth:nil 
           monthsOfTheYear:nil 
            weeksOfTheYear:nil 
             daysOfTheYear:nil 
              setPositions:nil 
                       end:nil
```

but it is not working, it just repeat event every day :S
When I try use EKRecurrenceFrequencyMonthly, then it works. It repeats event every month, but not on Sunday. I reported bug to Apple, because it seems that they have a bug.

Or you have other idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple documentation says:

@method     initRecurrenceWithFrequency:interval:daysOfTheWeek:daysOfTheMonth:monthsOfTheYear:weeksOfTheYear:daysOfTheYear:setPositions:end:

@abstract   The designated initializer.

@discussion This can be used to build any kind of recurrence rule. But be aware that **certain combinations make no sense** and will be ignored. For example, **if you pass daysOfTheWeek for a daily recurrence, they will be ignored**.

I think, we can't say it daily and say not on Sunday. Please let me know if I am mistaken.

Thanks.

Comment: hmm
yes that explain something, but it is stupid

i do not understand why it will be ignored, because I think it just makes sense.

For example I watch my favorite TV show every work day (every day except sunday and saturday).

Answer (score 4):

[Creating A Complex Recurrence Rule](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/CreatingRecurringEvents/CreatingRecurringEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009765-CH3-SW1)

*"Days of the week. For all recurrence rules besides daily recurrence rules, you can provide an array of EKRecurrenceDayOfWeek objects that indicate the days of the week on which the event occurs.
For example, you can provide an array containing EKRecurrenceDayOfWeek objects with day of week values of EKTuesday and EKFriday to create a recurrence that occurs every Tuesday and Friday."*

In other words, what you want to do is use Monday to Friday and then repeat that WEEKLY. Repeating Monday to Friday every day makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
initRecurrenceWithFrequency:EKRecurrenceFrequencyDaily 
                   interval:1 
              daysOfTheWeek:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                [EKRecurrenceDayOfWeek dayOfWeek:2],
                                [EKRecurrenceDayOfWeek dayOfWeek:3],
                                [EKRecurrenceDayOfWeek dayOfWeek:4],
                                [EKRecurrenceDayOfWeek dayOfWeek:5], 
                                [EKRecurrenceDayOfWeek dayOfWeek:6],
                                [EKRecurrenceDayOfWeek dayOfWeek:7], nil] 
            daysOfTheMonth:nil 
           monthsOfTheYear:nil 
            weeksOfTheYear:nil 
             daysOfTheYear:nil 
              setPositions:nil 
                       end:nil
```

In this code you are using `EKRecurrenceFrequencyDaily` and again specifying the days of a week. Instead of this try to execute with `EKRecurrenceFrequencyWeekly`

`EKRecurrenceDayOfWeek *weekReferecne=[[EKRecurrenceDayOfWeek alloc]initWithDayOfTheWeek:2 weekNumber:0];`

and create `EKRecurrenceDayOfWeek` objects with week number 0(zero) so that the EKAlarm repeats every day until you specify the enddate.. This code works. Have a Happy coding